# How to hide field and use ng-model for Rest Service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, angular-ngmodel

I have field that i want to hide permanently from the view but i want to use ng-model for Rest Service to do some calculation for other fields. How to achieve that task using AngularJS ?

So far tried code...

main.html

```
 <div class="form-group col-md-6" ng-disabled="disableEffComp" ng-hide="true">
    <div>
        <label class="control-label" for="controlEffect">Overall
           Control Effectiveness Computed</label>
    </div>
    <select kendo-drop-down-list k-data-value-field="'id'"
            k-data-text-field="'text'" k-option-label="'Select'"
            k-data-source="ctrlEffOptions"
            ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"
            ng-model="processRating.controlEffectivenessRatingComputeKey"
            readOnly="compReadOnly" id="controlEffect">
    </select>                   
</div>
```

mainCtrl.js

```
$scope.overrideBusinessDec = function () {
        if ($scope.processRating.controlEffectivenessRatingComputeKey && $scope.processRating.controlEffectivenessRatingOverrideKey !== $scope.processRating.controlEffectivenessRatingComputeKey) {
            Rating.getProcessRatingFields($scope.processRating.controlEffectivenessRatingOverrideKey, $scope.processRating.finalOutcomeInherentRiskRatingKey).then(function (response) {
                $scope.processRating.residualRiskRatingComputeKey = response.data.residualRiskRatingComputeKey;
                $scope.processRating.residualRiskRatingOverrideKey = response.data.residualRiskRatingComputeKey;
                $scope.riskBusinessOptions = response.data.residualRiskOverride;
            });
        }
    };
```

Comment: What exactly does the directive `ngModel` have to do with the REST service?

Comment: based on ngModel values there is calculation at backend and that display other fields

Comment: You could provide more information on what you want to achieve and how your current code fails to achieve that. Are there errors? If you don't want all data displayed, why not process in controller and only display portions of it?

Comment: Sounds like an XY Problem. The `ng-model` part doesn't make a lot of sense without more details

Comment: `ngModel` is a directive. I assume you rather mean based on `processRating.controlEffectivenessRatingComputeKey`.

Comment: I used angular ng-hide directive to hide field permanent and ngMOdel binding is working as expected thanks all for the answer